# check for convergence of finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let S$_k$ = $\sum\limits_{n=2}^k $ (-1)$^a$ $\frac{1}{\ln n}$ where a:=floor($n^{0.5} $)

Is S$_k$ convergent? Is S$_{2k^2}$ convergent?

I have just some vague idea how to show that both of them are (hopefully) divergent but no clue what would suffice as an "elegant" proof. Can anyone show me how to solve it in a nice way?

Comment: You say $a = \lfloor n \rfloor$. But as $n$ ranges across integers, it looks like $a = n$. Secondly, what do you mean by "Is $S_k$ convergent?" It's a finite sum. (Ah, you just edited in the answer to the first question)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Now it's correct. This exercise comes from my book. Are we safe in assuming that finite series are always convergent? What if we set k = $\infty$

Comment: I think the lower bound on the sum should be 2 to avoid division by 0

Comment: Did you try Dirichlet's test? The conditions fo $b_n = \frac{1}{\log n} $ are fulfilled, you only need to sound the other term by a constant.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm just starting to really wonder what sense it makes to test that if we assume the series is finite. The condition you point to is satisfied but what bound can we use to say that |A$_n$| < M ? If we assume finite series then M = k but b$_n$ does not tend to infinity (in finite case) . What if it is infinite? Then we have an infinite progression of 1's and -1's and series of a given sign tend to be ever longer so I guess there is no way of bounding them and thus Dirichlet wouldn't work in infinite case :(

Comment: I thought the series is infinite. I think the series is divergent, because the 'gaps' between squares grow by $2k+1$ terms.